# Should I put my billing module in it's own class library?

Tags: c#, class-library

I'm working on an Enterprise System which was originally built on a framework. When I got ownership of the application, I decide to build a new customer framework and transfer the entire system to it module by module with without breaking the entire application.

In my new framework I have a business, value object, and data access layers; which contain framework related classes. The billing module has been sitting in the old framework, but I want to improve on it and move it.

The question is do I move it into the new existing business, value object, and data access layers in my new framework or do i give the billing module a different class library of it's own, while I reference my framework DLLs? Please Pros and Cons are also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think that it can be usefull in other application , its better to build the different dll for the billing module.
Advantage of this is you do not need to write code again for the the other application.

Note : here other application may be WCF service, Desktop app, Web app etc. where you can utilize the billing module.